# Converting type inside Add method of DropDownList class

Tags: c#, .net, drop-down-menu

I have the following code segment:

```
var framelist = BL.FooBL.GetFrame() ;

        var           
        foreach( var i in framelist)
            {
                DropDownList.Items.Add(new ListItem(i.FrameModel,i.FrameTypeID)));

            }
```

I want to cast i.FrameTypeID from integer type to string type, but when I try to cast like this :

```
(i.FrameModel,(string)i.FrameTypeID)
```

But I get Error:

> Invalid anonymus type member declaration.

How can I convert this field to string inside Foreach statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var framelist = BL.FooBL.GetFrame() ;

var //This is what is causing your issue          
foreach( var i in framelist)
{
   DropDownList.Items.Add(new ListItem(i.FrameModel,i.FrameTypeID.ToString())));
}
```

You have a var floating out in your code there. This has nothing to do with the `Add` itself.

Comment: But apart from that, when `FrameTypeID` is an integer that wouldn't compile since [ListItem-Constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f7h2h8h.aspx) wants two strings. `new ListItem(i.FrameModel,i.FrameTypeID.ToString())` should work(if FrameModel is a string).

Comment: @TimSchmelter yea, I meant to add that part, but he had the type casting down without a problem.